# What's the correct way to use useRef and forwardRef together?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have two components: `App` and `Child`. I use `useRef` hook to get the DOM element in `Child` component and do some work with it.

I also pass `ref` from `App` component to `Child` component using `React.forwardRef` API.

`App.tsx`:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  console.log("App ref: ", ref);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Child.ts`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const innerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const divElement = ref || innerRef; // TSC throw error here.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (divElement.current) {
      console.log("clientWidth: ", divElement.current.clientWidth);
      // do something with divElement.current
    }
  }, []);
  return <div ref={divElement}></div>;
});
```

I am not sure it's a correct way to use `innerRef` and forwarded `ref` together like above. At least, the TSC throw an error which means it does NOT allow use it like this.

> Type '((instance: unknown) => void) | MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'RefObject'.
> Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'

I want to get the correct ref in `App` component and use this `ref` in Child component as well. How can I do this?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cookies-gruzi?file=/src/Child.tsx)

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/65877297/6106583

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73046577/5099971) explains the ref types and provides a React hook (in TypeScript) that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can largely ignore the TS error because you didn't provide types for the forwardRef arguments so it doesn't know that ref/innerRef are equivalently typed.

`const divElement = ref || innerRef;` `<div ref={divElement}></div>`

I don't understand this bit - do you want it to have a reference to the div element directly regardless of if the  is given a ref or not?

Anyway, I think if you want to get it working like this, it's best you use the `useImperativeHandle` hook like `useImperativeHandle(ref, () => innerRef.current);`

So, the Child component itself manages the ref with the `innerRef` but if someone does pass a ref to the Child component, it will yield that.

```
export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const innerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => innerRef.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (innerRef.current) {
      console.log("clientWidth: ", innerRef.current.clientWidth);
    }
  }, []);

  return <div ref={innerRef}></div>;
});
```

Comment: What you can do, to prevent the typescript error is to specify the type of forwardRef like this: `React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, yourOwnPropsType>((props, ref) => {...}` and use the handle like this: `useImperativeHandle(ref, () => innerRef.current as HTMLDivElement);
`

Comment: This should be part of the official documentation!

Comment: Nice! Or just use `!` in the end: `useImperativeHandle(ref, () => innerRef.current!)`

Comment: @Ziarno Unfortunately, can't use that non-null assertion in projects with the ESLint config that prevents that. `Forbidden non-null assertion. (eslint@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a solution with TypeScript and without `useImperativeHandle`, you can write this:

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  // more...
}

export default React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(({ children }, ref) => {
  const innerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
   
  const setRef = (element: HTMLDivElement) => {
    if (typeof ref === "function") ref(element);
    else if (ref) ref.current = element;
    innerRef.current = element;
    console.log("clientWidth: ", innerRef.current.clientWidth);
  };
    
  return <div ref={setRef}>{children}</div>;
});
```

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shadow-n83nmw?file=/src/App.tsx

The reason it works is that [the `ref` prop accepts a callback](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback), so you can execute whatever code you like when it triggers.
Here, we're setting both the `ref` value (which we said can be a function, thus the `if` / `else`) and our `innerRef`.

Note: there's nothing wrong with [`useImperativeHandle`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle), feel free to use it. Both solutions will perform the same.

Answer (score 1):

To access a ref while also forwarding it:

- Attach a ref created inside the component to the element
- Call the [`useImperativeHandle`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) hook on the outer ref (which is being forwarded to) and pass a function that returns the `current` property of the inner ref, which is the value that will be set to the `current` property of the outer ref

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
export default forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, outerRef) => {
  const innerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useImperativeHandle(outerRef, () => innerRef.current!, []);
  // remember to list any dependencies of the function that returns the ref value, similar to useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    if (innerRef.current) {
        // innerRef.current refers to the div element here
    }
  }, []);
  return <div ref={innerRef}></div>;
});
```