# What's the difference between React's ForwardedRef and RefObject?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

In a React codebase I'm working on I have a custom hook which accepts a RefObject as a parameter, and an accompanying Provider to be used with such hook:

```js
export const ScrollUtilsProvider = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ScrollUtilsProviderProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const scrollUtils = useScrollUtils(ref) // issue happens on this line
    return <div ref={ref}><ScrollUtilsContext.Provider value={scrollUtils}>{props.children}</ScrollUtilsContext.Provider></div>
  },
)

export const useScrollUtils = <T extends Element>(ref: RefObject<T>) => {
  return {
    // some cool functions w/ the passed ref
  }
}
```

The error message I receive:

```
Argument of type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
```

Digging into both types I realised they are really different:

```js
// from @types/react@17.0.0
interface RefObject<T> {
  readonly current: T | null;
}
type ForwardedRef<T> = ((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null;
```

My questions are:

- why are these types so different?
- is there a way to use a ForwardedRef as a RefObject?
- if not, is there anything that makes ForwardedRefs so special?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### RefObject

```js
interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null;
}
```

`RefObject` is the return type of the `React.createRef` method.

When this method is called, it returns an object with its only field `.current` set to `null`.  Soon after, when a `render` passes the ref to a component, React will set `.current` to a reference to the component. This component will generally be a DOM element (if passed to a HTML element) or an instance of a class component (if passed to a custom class component).

Note that `RefObject` is very similar to `MutableRefObject<T | null>`, with the exception that `.current` is `readonly`.  This type specification is only made to indicate that the `.current` property is managed internally by React and should not be modified by the code in a React app.

### MutableRefObject

```js
interface MutableRefObject<T> {
    current: T;
}
```

`MutableRefObject` is the return type of the `React.useRef` method. Internally, `React.useRef` makes a `MutableRefObject`, stores it to the state of the functional component, and returns the object.

Note that when objects are stored to the state of a React component, modifying their properties will not trigger a re-render (since Javascript objects are reference types).  This situation allows you to mimic class instance variables in functional components, which don't have instances. In other words, you can think of `React.useRef` as a way to associate a variable with a functional component without it affecting the component's renders.

Here's an example of a class component using instance variables and a functional component using `React.useRef` to achieve the same purpose:

```js
class ClassTimer extends React.Component {
    interval: NodeJS.Timer | null = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => { /* ... */ });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (!this.interval) return;
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    /* ... */
}

function FunctionalTimer() {
    const intervalRef = React.useRef<NodeJS.Timer>(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => { /* ... */ });
        return () => {
            if (!intervalRef.current) return;
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        };
    }, []);

    /* ... */
}
```

### ForwardedRef

```js
type ForwardedRef<T> = 
    | ((instance: T | null) => void)
    | MutableRefObject<T | null> 
    | null;
```

`ForwardedRef` is the type of ref React passes to functional components using `React.forwardRef`.

The main idea here is that parent components can pass a ref down to child components. For example, `MyForm` can forward a ref to `MyTextInput`, allowing the former to access the `.value` of the `HTMLInputElement` that the latter renders.

Breaking down the union type:

- `MutableRefObject<T | null>` - The forwarded ref was created with `React.useRef`.
- `((instance: T | null) => void)` - The forwarded ref is a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).
- `null` - No ref was forwarded.

### Using ForwardedRef in the child component

When a child component receives a `ForwardedRef`, it is often to expose the ref to a parent.  However, sometimes the child component may need to use the ref itself.  In this case, you can use a hook to the reconcile each of the `ForwardedRef` types listed above.

Here is a hook from [this article](https://non-traditional.dev/how-to-use-the-forwarded-ref-in-react-1fb108f4e6af) (adjusted for Typescript) that helps achieve this:

```js
function useForwardedRef<T>(ref: React.ForwardedRef<T>) {
    const innerRef = React.useRef<T>(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!ref) return;
        if (typeof ref === 'function') {
            ref(innerRef.current);
        } else {
            ref.current = innerRef.current;
        }
    });

    return innerRef;
}
```

The idea behind this hook is that the component can create its own ref, which it can use regardless of whether the parent forwarded a ref. The hook helps ensure that any forwarded ref's `.current` property is kept in sync with the inner one's.

The return type of this hook is `MutableRefObject<T>`, which should be compatible with the `RefObject<T>` argument in your code snippet for `useScrollUtils`, e.g.:

```js
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>(
    function MyComponent(_props, ref) {
        const innerRef = useForwardedRef(ref);

        useScrollUtils(innerRef);

        return <div ref={innerRef}></div>;
    }
);
```

Comment: This is a Pro move ;) Thanks

Comment: @rpatel about the `useForwardedRef()`, it sounds me strange the assignment inside else statement: `ref.current = innerRef.current`. You sure it's not the other way around `innerRef.current = ref.current;` since you're returning innerRef?

Comment: @SergioP Refs allow information to flow upward from child to parent.  Check out [callback refs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) and consider whether `ref(innerRef.current)` would be consistent with `innerRef.current = ref.current`.

Comment: @rpatel, I am running into a similar issue where the component defined with `forwardRef` does not care about the ref. In other words, if the parent passes a ref, it should forward it, otherwise it doesn't care. However, I am getting a TypeScript error in my solution when I don't pass a ref. Would you mind helping. Here's the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77714819/how-to-specify-that-forwardref-is-optional-in-a-react-component).