# Use ref in forward ref functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom input component that looks something like this:

```
export const CustomInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // HOW CAN I DO THIS???`
    console.log(ref.current.target.value);
  }, []);

  return <input ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

I need to be able to see the value of the `<input />` element using `ref.current.target.value`. How can I do this?

To be clear, `ref.current...` doesn't work because it's a `ForwardedRef` not a normal ref. This is what I get when I print the forwarded ref:

```
(ref) => {
        if (ref) {
          register(name, options);
          field = get(_fields, name);
          const fieldRef = isUndefined(ref.value) ? ref.querySelectorAll ? ref.querySelectorAll("input,select,textarea")[0] || ref : ref : ref;
          const radioOrCheckbox = isRadioOrCheckbox(fieldRef);
          const refs = field._f.refs || [];
          if (radioOrCheckbox ? refs.find((option) => option === fieldRef) : fieldRef === field._f.ref) {
            return;
          }
          set(_fields, name, {
            _f: {
              ...field._f,
              ...radioOrCheckbox ? {
                refs: [
                  ...refs.filter(live),
                  fieldRef,
                  ...Array.isArray(get(_defaultValues, name)) ? [{}] : []
                ],
                ref: { type: fieldRef.type, name }
              } : { ref: fieldRef }
            }
          });
          updateValidAndValue(name, false, void 0, fieldRef);
        } else {
          field = get(_fields, name, {});
          if (field._f) {
            field._f.mount = false;
          }
          (_options.shouldUnregister || options.shouldUnregister) && !(isNameInFieldArray(_names.array, name) && _state.action) && _names.unMount.add(name);
        }
      }
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the above code? Is it not working or printing to console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between React's ForwardedRef and RefObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015696/whats-the-difference-between-reacts-forwardedref-and-refobject)