# Forwarding ref to child component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I am trying to forward ref to input through to child component but even tough it seems to work, TS is throwing errors that I dont know what to do with. It throws that "Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'." Would appreciate your help with solving it cause I haven't really been forwarding refs yet and I don't have any experience with it.

**Child Component**

```
const AddComment = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>((props, ref) => {
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref!.current!.focus();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <AddCommentWrapper>
      <ProfileIcon image={avatar} />
      <AddCommentInput
        ref={ref}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Write a comment..."
        isDarkMode={isDarkMode}
      />
    </AddCommentWrapper>
  );
});
export default AddComment;
```

**Parent Component**

```
const CommentsSection = ({ comments }: CommentsSectionProps) => {
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const commentsToShow = showMore ? comments : comments?.slice(0, 1);

  const focusOnInput = () => {
    inputRef!.current!.focus();
  };

  return (
    <CommentsWrapper>
      <AddComment ref={inputRef} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876809/property-current-does-not-exist-on-type-instance-htmldivelement-null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876809/property-current-does-not-exist-on-type-instance-htmldivelement-null)